# Django - Problems with PDF upload

Tags: python, django, pdf

I got another problem with Django. I want to upload an PDF with an Form in the template, when I click upload in my form, this happens:

```
Cannot assign "<InMemoryUploadedFile: thebook.pdf (application/pdf)>": "Product.book" must be a "File" instance.
```

This is the line in my model

```
book = FilerFileField(null=true,blank=true)
```

This is the line in my form

```
book = forms.FileField(label=u"Book Upload")
```

Comment: What is FilerFileField?

Comment: Just a simple File-Upload field... Did I get something wrong? I'm pretty new to Django/Python

Comment: Its from django-filer egg

Comment: You're going to need to show more code. What does the rest of the form look like? What about the view? How are you assigning the file? How are you saving the model?

Answer (score 1):

Django's `forms.FileField` expects an `UploadedFile`. Whereby the FilerFileField is actually a subclasses of `django.db.models.ForeignKey`. Therefor you should use a `ChoiceField` at your form.

```
book = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=filer.models.File.objects.all())
```

See also django-filer's usage notes and django's docs on the `ModelChoiceField`:

- http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Comment: This will go through all my files and list them. But I want the user to upload something, not use the existing Files